# Band-pass and LM358 based rhythmic light

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, comparator, band-pass

I was asked by a friend to build a simple circuit to have a light flash depending on the bass of a song (mainly techno music).

This is my idea:

[image: circuit]

The circuit works on 9V to be powered either by battery or power supply. The audio comes from X1 (a 3.5mm jack port) and goes through a LC bandpass filter comprising the 10kOhm pot (to control the "steepness" of the filter), 453 mH inductor and a choosable capacitor to change the central band of the filter.

The filtered signal is biased by the R4-R5 voltage divider and amplified by the first half of the LM358 (gain controlled with the 1kOhm pot). The amplified signal is decoupled by C4 and rectified by D1. This causes only the bass "bumps" to come through. Moreover now the signal can be amplified further by the second half of the first LM358. In this case the gain is fixed and decided by the  10K trimpot.

At this point the signal is split in two rails, each one going to one half of another LM358 used as comparators. The top half is a fixed comparator and drives a LED when the input voltage is over 7.5V. This is close to the maximum allowed voltage of the amplifier and works as a sort of warning that the amp is getting saturated. The other half of the LM538 is the comparator that drives the light by activating a relay. Additionally a LED is present to give an idea of the output signal.

I am already aware that probably I will need a transistor to properly drive the coil of the relay but I'm still in prototyping stage and I still don't know what type of light will be attached at the end (LED, strobo, ...).

So now to the actual question(s).

1) are there any evident flaws in the design? I tested the circuit and works fine but maybe some of you can give me some feedback

2) since I want to make a nice PCB for my friend but I don't have any experience in designing PCBs, are there any points I should be aware of when laying the PCB out? BTW I'm using EAGLE for the design.

Comment: Are you using a relay to switch lights on and off multiple times a second? Or is it on if music's playing and off if not?

Comment: The 1st flaw is lack of design specs to compare results.  BW, attack time, decay, linearity , output?

Comment: @DiBosco If you imagine the spectrum of a song (whichever), it switches on when the beat "starts" and off when the beat "ends". For the general techno song I would assume 100-120 bpm (beats per minute)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 you know.... **beats** .... 1 Hz - 3Hz. Seems to me a PLL would work, so long as you can phase-lock onto the beat leading edge.

Comment: Input Caps are reverse polarized.  Pots have no RefDes and change RC response with gain

Comment: I must say I would think that's a bit much for a relay.  You're switching on mains powered lights?

Comment: As a learning exercise , you will be satisfied with showing what you know how to do but also  learn a lot about what you need to learn.   Here is a 5 channel unit that uses triacs to drive 2.5A or 700W ac .  We call this a Make or Buy option.  https://www.amazon.com/5-Channel-Light-Organ-Kit/dp/B004HMW6HM  They often use Gyrator Amp filters to simulate inductors

Comment: Amplifier_B should be wired as an ideal rectifier, as you have it configured after C4 is charged there will be no more signal into it.

Comment: the relay should be replaced with a power transistor or a solid-state relay. (triac driver and triac) at 120+ BPM techno will destroy a mechanical relay fairly quickly.

Comment: if you want to see other people's approaches to this search the web for "color organ schematic"

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I put the caps wrong on the schematic. Sorry for that. What do you mean with the pots?

Comment: @Jasen I will look into solid state relays

Comment: Besides, why was this downvoted?

Comment: REFDES means Reference Designators like RV1 for variable Rs

Comment: You have no right to expect the relay to operate. Nominal coil current for a 9 volt G5SB is 45 mA, which is way more than you can expect from a wimpy little LM358.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast in fact I specified that I probably would need a transistor to drive properly the coil. Nevertheless I also specified that I still don't know which kind of load my friend wants to drive

Answer (score 2):

> are there any evident flaws in the design?

I can only see one error: -

[image]

Comment: doesn't need it. I want to amplify just the positive part of the wave to get maximum amplification. I don't really care for the negative side

Comment: @Luca Don't you see why Andy's comment still applies, even given your desires here?

Comment: Hint: One of the lines in your op-amp's datasheet is "input bias current".

Comment: @ThePhoton so I should put a 100-odd kOhm resistor tied to +V to get some current into the input pin?

Comment: @jonk my point being, on a breadboard the circuit works. Someone cares to elaborate why?

Comment: @Luca, look at the schematic in the datasheet. The inputs are PNP and you'd  probably need to connect your bias resistors to GND. Even better would be to put some circuit that provides a known bias voltage even if the input currents vary by a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: It works because the reverse leakage current of a 5819 is going to be significantly greater than the LM358 bias current.

Comment: @MattYoung That makes sense. I added a 1MOhm resistor between the point and GND